# Joining existing windows servers in the AD Azure domain

Tags: windows, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

We did AD on premise synchronization with AD Azure. Now we are thinking of disabling (kill the server and all users log into desktops with their respective accounts in office 365) AD On premises, staying with AD only in the cloud, and inserting other servers only in AD Azure.

Can we do this step?
Or we should migrate these servers to azure and then insert into the domain?

I researched on the subject and it just seems to work with virtual machines within the azure itself, not outside the azure environment.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have seen [Azure AD Domain Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview).

> I researched on the subject and it just seems to work with virtual
>   machines within the azure itself, not outside the azure environment.

**Not really.** You can join machines to this managed domain using traditional domain-join mechanisms. This needs your set up site-to-site VPN between Azure and your On-premise. You can even setup a hybird envrionment like this:

[image]

The domain joined machine needs to be connected to the managed domain over a peered virtual network or over a site-to-site VPN/ExpressRoute connection. Thus, this mechanism isn't a great fit for devices that are mobile or connect to resources from outside the corporate network.

> **NOTE:** Technically, it is possible to join an on-premises client workstation
>   to the managed domain over a site-to-site VPN or ExpressRoute
>   connection. However, for end-user devices we strongly recommend you
>   use either register the device with Azure AD (personal devices) or
>   join the device to Azure AD (corporate devices). This mechanism works
>   better over the internet and enables end users to work from anywhere.
>   Azure AD Domain Services is great for Windows or Linux Server virtual
>   machines deployed in your Azure virtual networks, on which your
>   applications are deployed.

Also,if all your deivces are all Windows 10, I think Azure AD join is a better choice.

Choosing between Azure Active Directory join and Azure Active Directory Domain Services, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-compare-with-azure-ad-join).

Comment: Why is all of this VPN needed - why can't it connect DIRECTLY to the cloud?